# Tags layout in question block

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app

Incorrect tags layout in block for specific [question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3839/176217):

[image: tags layout]

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.1.1.

The problem was that we were always calculating the height assuming it was showing the post creation date, even if it was showing the last active date.  In this specific case, the creation date was probably "2 days ago", meaning both tags fit on a single line in the height calculation.  Since "11 hours ago" is slightly wider, it forced the tags onto two lines when it was actually displayed.

As a side note, this issue will still crop up in some circumstances, like when the height is calculated at "9 mins ago" and it goes to "10 mins ago".  Fixing that would probably involve resolving dates around a fixed point in time (e.g., load time), and I probably won't implement that in the near future.