# Tags layout in question block (2)

Tags: bug, design, ios-app

Same issue as [already fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285425/339911), but occurred when tag is word-wrapped:

> [image: tagsww]

Turns out that is not for word-wrapped tags only:

> [image: 3tag]

I.e. It is completely same issue as described in the beginning.

Yet another [question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623895/176217) where issue is in action:

> [image: 5tag]

Seems happening only when app gets posts for the first time. You can refresh question list by swipe with no effect. But if you switch site and return back it looks OK already:

> [image: 5tagok]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: @downvoter, do you think this formatting is OK?

Comment: No, but he probably thinks your question lacks detail, is horribly formatted, doesn't contribute, is bad in general, not a bug, or off-topic.

Comment: I'm just listing most commonly used reasons for downvotes, I do not wish to imply that your question is either of these.